# What is ../.. , ../

Tags: javascript

I have strugure folder like this

```
root
  || client
  || libs  \\bower install 
   ||src
       index.html
```

In index I try inject  `../jquery.js` but I get not found . Where is my wrong . And I want ask what is `../..` , `'../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`../jQuery.js` means the file `jQuery.js` in the previous (parent) directory. So a not found means that the file isn't in the `libs` folder. In Unix, `../` means the previous folder and you can go back as many folders as you want, so `../../` means 2 parents folders and so on. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

`../..` means two levels up in the directory hierarchy. `..` is one level up.

Assuming your `jquery.js` file is in the `libs` folder, you want `../../jquery.js`. The `../..` moves you up two levels from `index.html`: to `src` then `libs`. Since you're in the `libs` directory at that point, you can do `/jquery.js` to reference jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

In this context the '..' characters means up one folder. If you want to get to your jQuery file you would need it in your folder structure somewhere and access it at the right place.